# Logs showing errors related to docker

Tags: angular, azure, gitlab-ci

I want to deploy the angular application using `gitlab ci/cd pipeline` to **azure**, I created the gitlab pipeline, Refer below:-

[image]

After deployment the problem is in logs showing below errors:-

[image]

Please help me to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

***This happens if the deployment is not done properly or if any files missing.***

- I was seeing the *same logs* and was unable to access the deployed application ***when I deployed my Angular Application to Linux Azure App Service.***
- Hence, I deployed the same **Angular Application (dist folder of the project**) to **windows** and could run & access the application successfully.

**Steps followed:**

- Created Angular Application with the command `ng new my-app`.
- Build the project with the command `ng build`, it generates `dist folder` with the necessary files for the deployment.

[image]

[image]

- Deploy ***Only the dist folder*** to **Azure App Service**.
- After successful deployment, navigate to `Advanced Tools in App Service=>Go=>Opens KUDU site=>Debug Console=>cmd=>open site/wwwroot folder`, make sure the project files are available as shown below:

[image]

- Copy the ***Project_Name***(`my_angularapp` as shown above), navigate to `App Service=>Configuration=>PathMappings=> Virtual applications and directories` , edit *physical path* **`site\wwwroot`**, add **`project_name`** to the path:

[image]

- ***Test the application by running the URL* `https://<your_AppService_name>.azurewebsites.net`:**

[image]